# Gitlab: Server hooks custom error messages not displaying on merge requests

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, gitlab-ce

I've been trying to implement [Server hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html) on a self-hosted Gitlab (CE) instance and its been working so far.

However, part of the **custom_hooks** validate if pushes to certain branches are squashed, so only allow one commit to being pushed and it displays an error message otherwise. This works fine on locally with `git push` but not on the Merge Request.

According to the documentation, it allows [Custom error messages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#custom-error-messages) to display on there but that doesn't seem to work.

So I've a simpler version that always exits with an error to validate the error is showing properly.

> Locally

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.03 KiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GL-HOOK-ERR: My custom error message.
To gitlab.sample.co.uk:praveen.premaratne/dummy.git
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.sample.co.uk:praveen.premaratne/dummy.git'
```

> Merge Request
> [image: image|690x267]

> Gitlab version details

[image: image|690x327]

Is this documentation still update? Or does anyone able to help me with getting the error message to display on Merge Request?

*Ps: I've tried asking on Gitlab forum but it's been 4 days and I haven't heard anything.*

Comment: This is stil a very annoying issue.  I have tried sending output on stdout and stderr and I just get the unhelpful generic error message.  I cannot believe this is intentional, I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your script prints anything else other than the desired error message prefixed with "GL-HOOK_ERR:" this will fail. A warning message from mysql was upsetting things in my script.